# Invariant failed: Cannot find droppable entry with id [droppable]

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, draggable, react-beautiful-dnd

Working with react table and requirement is to make the rows draggable. Below is the short view of my code.

```
 <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd} onDragUpdate={onDragUpdate}>
     <Droppable droppableId="droppable">
     {(provided) => (
          <TableBody {...provided.droppableProps} ref={provided.innerRef}>
          {inventory.map((row, index) => (
           <Draggable key={row.accountId} draggableId={row.accountId.toString()} 
              index={index}>
                 {(provided, snapshot) => (
                     <TableRow ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.draggableProps}
                       style={getItemStyle(snapshot.isDragging,
                              provided.draggableProps.style)}>
```

I am getting result.destination as null in onDragEnd method. What's going wrong here?